# Error message mentions that my dataset is small

Tags: r, package, dataset, bioinformatics

So I need to use the R package "humboldt" (https://github.com/jasonleebrown/humboldt) to reduce the climate variables that affect some animal species. The code I wrote is the following:

```
> env1<-read.delim("Env1.csv",h=T,sep=",")
> env2 <-read.delim("Env1.csv",h=T,sep=",")
> sp1<- na.exclude(read.delim("Sp1.csv",h=T,sep=","))
> sp2<- na.exclude(read.delim("Sp2.csv",h=T,sep=","))
> reduc.vars<- humboldt.top.env(env1=env1,env2=env2,sp1=sp1,sp2=sp2,rarefy.dist=50, rarefy.units="km", env.reso=0.416669,learning.rt1=0.01,learning.rt2=0.01,e.var=(4:17),pa.ratio=4,steps1=50,steps2=50,method="contrib",contrib.greater=5)
```

Now this is the last step of the process but this error message pops up after the last command
Error in gbm.fit(x = x, y = y, offset = offset, distribution = distribution,  :
The data set is too small or the subsampling rate is too large: `nTrain * bag.fraction <= n.minobsinnode`

Comment: Check `NROW(env1); NROW(env2); ...` etc. or `summary(env1)....` to see wether it is a problem with the data. Also i see you're using the same file "Env1.csv" both in `env1` and `env2` is that a typo?

Comment: @RicVillalba So I checked the datasets out but I cant find anything wrong with the numbers. As far as the last thing you pointed out its not a typo Its an option you have with the package. I only want this env and to get results I set both env1 and env2 as Env1.csv